# Plotting decision tree results from tidymodels

Tags: r, decision-tree, tidymodels

I have managed to build a decision tree model using the `tidymodels` package but I am unsure how to pull the results and plot the tree. I know I can use the `rpart` and `rpart.plot` packages to achieve the same thing but I would rather use `tidymodels` as that is what I am learning. Below is an example using the `mtcars` data.

```
library(tidymodels)
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
library(dplyr) #contains mtcars

#data
df <- mtcars %>%
    mutate(gear = factor(gear))


#train/test
set.seed(1234)

df_split <- initial_split(df)
df_train <- training(df_split)
df_test <- testing(df_split)


df_recipe <- recipe(gear~ ., data = df) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric())


#building model
tree <- decision_tree() %>%
   set_engine("rpart") %>%
   set_mode("classification")

#workflow
 tree_wf <- workflow() %>%
   add_recipe(df_recipe) %>%
   add_model(tree) %>%
   fit(df_train) #results are found here 

rpart.plot(tree_wf$fit$fit) #error is here
```

The error I get says `Error in rpart.plot(tree_wf$fit$fit) : Not an rpart object` which makes sense but I am unaware if there is a package or step I am missing to convert the results into a format that `rpart.plot` will allow me to plot. This might not be possible but any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also use the `workflows::pull_workflow_fit()` function. It makes the code a little bit more elegant.

```
tree_fit <- tree_wf %>% 
  pull_workflow_fit()
rpart.plot(tree_fit$fit)
```

Answer (score 7):

The following works (note the extra `$fit`):

```
rpart.plot(tree_wf$fit$fit$fit)
```

Not a very elegant solution, but it does plot the tree.

Tested with parsnip 0.1.3 and rpart.plot 3.0.8.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution mapping to the present state of tidymodels:

```r
tree_fit_rpart <- extract_fit_engine(tree_wf)
rpart.plot(tree_fit_rpart)
```